# DRF Serializer custom create

Tags: django-rest-framework

I don't know if I'm doing this the right way, but I'm having problems with saving some relations with DRF serializers.

Let's say I have a MessageBoard and some MessageBoardPosts

Post has a serializer like:

```
class MessageBoardPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
      model = MessageBoardPost
      fields = '__all__'
```

I want to add a Post by posting to /api/messageBoards/[PK]/create_post/
To do this, I added an action to the MessageBoard Viewset:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['post'], permission_classes=[MatchesMessageboardVisibility])
def create_post(self, request, pk=None):
    # Messageboard to post to
    messageBoard = MessageBoard.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if messageBoard is not None:
        serializer = MessageBoardPostSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Since MessageBoard is a required FK on a post, I get validation errors when creating the post in the viewset.

What's the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializer (i assume that "message_board" is ForeignKey in MessageBoardPost model):

```
class MessageBoardPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  # this is read only by default which means serializer will not require that field 
  message_board = serializers.StringRelatedField() 

  class Meta:
      model = MessageBoardPost
      fields = '__all__'
```

Viewset action:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['post'], permission_classes=[MatchesMessageboardVisibility])
def create_post(self, request, pk=None):
    # Messageboard to post to
    messageBoard = get_object_or_404(MessageBoard, pk=pk)

    serializer = MessageBoardPostSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    # here you can pass data without validation directly to the save method
    serializer.save(message_board=messageBoard)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

- you should write your variables in snake_case style like "message_board" etc.
- for more advanced crud you should make url like /api/message-boards/PK/posts/ where you will POST your posts and message_board should be prefetched in overrited initial method

Comment: well, i was a bit fast ... indeed some trouble with it too ... think i should add some custom validation or just not raise an exception when calling isvalid

Comment: Add some troubles here in comments, i can help you and edit answer.

Comment: I just don't think we need to raise_exception when validating. Message_board is a required field on the post. Since we pass it on save, the validation already threw an exception.

I'll take a look at your advanced crud suggestion ;-). thanks!

Comment: You should always raise_exception if data is not correct. Can you please show what fields validation error contains ?

Comment: Hmmm.. try to update serializer message_board field to: serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True). Of course field name "message_board" should be exactly the same as the model field name. Try to experiment with "message_board_id" serializer field name if it will not help.

Comment: Awesome ... works now. Reading in the docs now, thanks for hinting me to the working solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the MessageBoard as context to the serializer:

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@action(detail=True, methods=['post'], permission_classes=[MatchesMessageboardVisibility])
def create_post(self, request, pk=None):
    # Messageboard to post to
    message_board = get_object_or_404(MessageBoard, pk=pk)

    context = {'message_board': message_board}
    serializer = MessageBoardPostSerializer(data=request.data, context=context)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```py
class MessageBoardPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MessageBoardPost
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        post = MessageBoardPost(**validated_data)
        post.message_board = self.context['message_board']
        post.save()
        return post
```